# Event handlers and components in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How would I specify a kind of change/input handler to be used by a component in vue.js, when I already have one in place in the component? I have a text input which in very simplified form is akin to this:

```
Vue.component('text-input', {
template: '\
<span>\
  $\
  <input\
    ref="input"\
    v-bind:value="value"\
    v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"\
  >\
   </span>\
  ' ,
props: ['value'],
methods: {
    updateValue: function (value) {
        this.$emit('input', value);
    },
    uppercase:function(value){
       return value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
});
```

I would use it like this:

```
<text-input v-model="name"></text-input>
```

It works fine, and updates correctly using the events system (with $emit). But now I want to convert the entered value to uppercase, so would presumably want to pass in an input handler which is the name of the method, such as 'uppercase', in my 'text-input' component. So I would have this:

```
<text-input v-model="name" @input="uppercase"></text-input>
```

But within my component, @input is already used by updateValue. How can I combine the two? (Or, perhaps, is there a different and better way of thinking this whole problem?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a bit of a hard time following, but if you wanted to run two functions on the same event you can just do two things in one function.

```
@input="update"
```

Then something like:

```
update: function (event) {
  this.updateValue(event.target.value)
  this.somethingElse()
}
```

Though, if the code you have is really what you're trying to do you can do:

```
this.$emit('input', this.uppercase(value))
```

After discussing a bit more in the comments. You can pass a custom callback as a property if you'd like and call that instead of whatever the default is. Here's a quick fiddle of one way to approach that: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/3xwmgpom/

Comment: OK, please bear with me here, I'm sure the answer is as obvious as you suggest, but I still can't see quite how this would be done. I have a generic text-input component, which I use without specifying any input handler for it - that is the job of the nested input: `v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)`. I want to be able to occasionally use a property on text-input which effectively tells the nested input to use a different method as handler (one which will contain the updateValue, as mentioned, as well as its own functionality) .

Comment: Do you essentially want something like these https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Modifiers but with the ability to say like.. `v-model.uppercase="foo"`?

Comment: Well, that would answer the specific requirement I mentioned. More generally, though, what I'm after is some way I can have an optional property for a component which is the name of a method to be used as an event handler by the contained input control. As I mentioned, it already has  a default one ('updateValue'). I would like to be able to specify a different one to use instead.

Comment: I adjusted my answer, but here's one approach to do what I think you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/3xwmgpom/

Comment: Yes, that's nearly it! What I was missing was the `inputCallback: Function`, defining the prop as a function. This pretty well gets me there. The only thing is that this is calling a method of the root instance (or parent component). What I want to do is call a method of the component itself - just not the default one, but the one named in the property.

Comment: You can make the prop a string instead and call it like... `var callback = this[this.callbackName]` then `if (callback) { callback(value) }` in that case.